# MATLAB Undefined function error

Tags: matlab

I tried running the following image compression code on matlab. It was running properly with no errors up til yesterday. But today when I tried to run it, It gave me errors regarding undefined function imshow, wavedec2, etc.

**ERRORS:**

```
??? Undefined function or method 'wavedec2' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
Error in ==> wave_project at 45
[c,s]=wavedec2(input_image,n,wname);

??? Undefined function or method 'imshow' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
Error in ==> wave_project at 17
imshow(input_image);
```

I checked the various toolboxes I have by VER command and Image processing toolbox is in it!

This has happened with me before. But the program then, ran afterwards.

**PROGRAM:**

```
clear all;
close all;

input_imag7e1 = imread('101_1.tif');
input_image=imnoise(input_image1,'speckle',0.01);

figure;

imshow(input_image);

p=input('enter the number of vanishing moments of wavelett M ');
n=input('enter the decomposition level');

wname = strcat('db',int2str(p));
disp(wname);

[c,s]=wavedec2(input_image,n,wname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are running a version of matlab that must check those toolboxes out from a central repository. If so, and there are currently too many people using that specific toolbox, then matlab does not assign you a license. We had this problem in the past. The only fix when it happened too often was to get the admin person to buy more licenses of that toolbox, or to run at an hour when others had released their license.

John

Comment: doesn't this problem give a license error, rather than undefined function? Something like "License Manager Error -4
Maximum number of users for "..." reached. Try again later."

Comment: You can check with [license](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/license.html)